# How to iterate over a generator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Assume a big list and I want to iterate over it.

```
>>> x=[]
>>> for i in x:
print(x)
```

but because the list is too big, using the generator is the best way:

```
>>> g=(i for i in range(10))
>>> g.__next__()
0
```

But there is a problem with number of times to iterate.
Because I don't know how many times I should use `g.__next__()`, I need something more dynamic.

For example:

```
for i in x:
```

It is not important how long is x as the loop with iterate to the end.

**How can I similarly iterate using generators?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `for` syntax with generators:

```
>>> g=(i for i in range(10))
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd70d42b0f0>
>>> for i in g:
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: if use for loop , does it has generators property ? I mean optimize usage of CPU and RAM ?

Comment: @ZeroDays if you;re asking whether the generator only generates a value when needed (as opposed to generating them up-front), the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Use for loop , just as you used in case of list , Example -

```
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

Comment: if  use for loop  , does it has generators property ?
I mean optimize usage of CPU and RAM ?

Comment: Yes , memory wise it does not create extra list or such. It just calls the next() function and iterates over it and then again calls next() and iterates over that , and so on . Not sure what you mean by optimising CPU of generators ?